# maven release:prepare FAILS due to 1.7 svn working copy (expects 1.6)

Tags: svn, maven, subclipse, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

I have had it up to HERE with maven! I finally get things working and running, and then I have attempted to do my first maven release:prepare using an external maven runtime THROUGH m2eclipse.

Here is the issue I am experiencing:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) on project scs-global-parent: Unable to commit files

[ERROR] Provider message:
The svn command failed.

Command output:
svn: The path 'C:\Users\Sam\MyProj\model\scs-global-parent' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this working copy.

I am using Subclipse 1.8.x - which supports 1.7 working copies? There must be a workaround ... what am I missing here?? Do I need to add an "experimental" version of the maven-release-plugin? Currently I am using the "default" in that I don't have a version specified in my pom or settings.xml. Thank you!!

Which "subversion client" is the plugin yelling at me about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maven will be using whatever subversion you have on your system accessible from the command line.

Check that the version of Subversion that runs from command line.  (use `svn --version` from a command prompt or shell).  Upgrade that particular version of Subversion on your system and it should work.

Comment: I completely and totally forgot that I had subversion installed on my PC. I have 1.6 installed on my PC, from the old days when I didn't have external servers and used it for college projects. Thank you so much for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use svnjava provider it supports 1.7 see http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/maven-scm-provider-svnjava/

More details: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/maven-scm-provider-svnjava/wiki/UsingWithReleasePlugin